# How secure is winzip encryption?

Tags: windows, security, encryption, zip, winzip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is zip's encryption really bad?](https://superuser.com/questions/145167/is-zips-encryption-really-bad)

Just how secure is winzip (http://www.winzip.com/) encryption?

Can you point me to any articles or anything like that where a zip has been cracked?